# Linked List contains function returns false, why? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

Singly linked list javascript implementation.
It returns true for the head but all other nodes return false.
Why contains method return false?
I think something wrong will my add toTail function. 
But when I'm printing linked list it is giving me all nodes

```js
"use strict";
var LinkedList = function(){
  this.head = null
}
var node = function(value){
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
}
LinkedList.prototype.addToHead = function(value){
  var n = new node(value);
  
  if(!this.head){
    this.head = n;
    
  }else{
      this.next = this.head;
      this.head = n;
    }
};


LinkedList.prototype.addToTail = function(value){
  var cur = null;
  var n = new node(value)
  if(!this.head){
    this.head = n;
  }else{
    cur = this.head;
    while(cur.next){
      cur = cur.next;
    }
    cur.next = n;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  var node = this.head;
  while (node) {
    if (node.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    node = node.next;
  }
  return false;
};

var ll = new LinkedList();
ll.addToTail(20)
ll.addToTail(40)
ll.addToHead(8)
console.log(ll.contains(40))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is in your addToHead function. Currently you are losing your list if a head already exists:

```js
"use strict";
var LinkedList = function(){
  this.head = null
}
var node = function(value){
  this.value = value;
  this.next = null;
}
LinkedList.prototype.addToHead = function(value){
  var n = new node(value);
  
  if(!this.head){
    this.head = n;
    
  }else{
      // this.next = this.head; <- What you had
      n.next = this.head; // What it should be
      this.head = n;
    }
};


LinkedList.prototype.addToTail = function(value){
  var cur = null;
  var n = new node(value)
  if(!this.head){
    this.head = n;
  }else{
    cur = this.head;
    while(cur.next){
      cur = cur.next;
    }
    cur.next = n;
  }
}

LinkedList.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  var node = this.head;
  while (node) {
    if (node.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    node = node.next;
  }
  return false;
};

var ll = new LinkedList();
ll.addToTail(20)
ll.addToTail(40)
ll.addToHead(8)
console.log(ll.contains(40))
```